# ubuntu sdk qml Quick view window close, minimize button not visible

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qml

This is my first time using QT and the Ubuntu SDK. In order to restrict the view size, i set a minimum and maximum height/width for the view:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setMaximumHeight((600));
    view.setMaximumWidth((800));
    view.setMinimumHeight((600));
    view.setMinimumWidth((800));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

However after adding the Max/min height/width attributes, the minimize and close buttons have disappeared from the application. Any way i can bring them back while maintaining the restriction of the view size? I have tried searching but couldn't find similar issue.

Thanks.

Comment: For now I've just set maximum to + 1 as a work around. This brings all the buttons (minimize, maximize, close) back but i still want to disable the maximize button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick workaround is to use setMaximumHeight/Width and set them to +1.

```
    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setMaximumHeight((601));
    view.setMaximumWidth((801));
    view.setMinimumHeight((600));
    view.setMinimumWidth((800));
```

This way the window can't resize any more than that 1 pixel and at the same time, the minimize, close buttons don't disappear.